# Delete everything from the left of </a></p> on Excel

Tags: excel

How could I go about deleting everything from the left of `</a></p>` in Excel

Would this work if I just put the characters where the `:` are

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(F2,LEN(F2)-SEARCH("@#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","@#",LEN(F2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F2,":",""))))))
```

Comment: Post a sample of the input text: how it looks like, and how do you want it to be after the replacement

Comment: Before <p><a class="btn" onclick="link" href="http://www.knittinganyway.com/socks/sockti9.gif" target="_blank">Size Chart</a></p> <p>Kerrits&reg

Comment: After <p>Kerrits&reg but the link inside will be different inside the row for everyline.

Comment: Please edit your question. Don't put put data samples into comments. Why are you editing HTML in Excel? What is the bigger picture. The result you describe will not be a link, just text, so what do you mean by "the link will be different"?

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**

```
=MID(A1,FIND("</a></p>",A1),9999)
```

so if **A1** contains:

```
nvkslkvjsdkvjkdjk</a></p>qwertyuiop
```

the function will return:

```
</a></p>qwertyuiop
```